# Less-serious-sounding word than 'problem'

Tags: word-usage

I don't like to say 'problem' since it sounds like I have a serious problem. Is there any adjectives that I can add so that it doesn't sound serious.

I'm talking about something about food I eat. For example:

> I'm not picky about the food I eat. There are few foods I don't like to eat. And I'm a person who likes to do something new and even when it comes to foods, I like to try something that I haven't eaten before. But, **I have a problem with eating**. I mean there are times when I eat more than I should if I don't want to feel too full.

I don't like to say 'problem' since it sounds like I have a serious problem. Is there any adjectives that I can add so that it doesn't sound serious. Or doesn't it sound like I have a serious problem with eating – like eating disorder – even though I just say it as stated here?

Comment: You could say that you have *difficulty eating*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to mention a problem at all -- your *but* implies sufficient contrast between the positive things about your diet and the negative effect of overeating. You might want to change that "conditional" effect to a definite effect, to underscore the negative quality.

> I'm not picky about the food I eat. There are few foods I don't like to eat. And I'm a person who likes to do something new and even when it comes to foods, I like to try something that I haven't eaten before. But there are times when I eat more than I should—and feel too full.

Comment: how about this? "I have something of a problem with eating? "

Answer (score 3):

I like StoneyB's answer.  He removed the adjective from the equation, thereby nullifying its negative connotations.  And *that* is the problem/issue/mess/complication/pickle/obstacle/trouble.  As you can see from the string of synonyms (different words with the same meaning), that it is not the word you say, but *how* it is said.  Adding context gives meaning.

For example:

- The dead battery is a problem.

That seems pretty benign.

Take this example:

- The dead battery which controls the nuclear reactor is a problem

With a little more information, the same "problem" becomes more serious.

Answer (score 2):

You can just describe it as a "small problem." As you say, "I have a problem with eating" sounds a bit ominous by itself. Something like "I have a small eating problem" or "I have a small problem with eating" seems like it would fit your purposes just fine. Other adjectives work too, like "minor problem." You could also describe it as an "inconvenience" instead of a problem.